# Correcting Spearman's rank correlation for measurement error and range restriction

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, measurement-error

Many articles describe how to correct the Pearson correlation for both measurement error and range restriction.<sup>1,2,3</sup> For some work I am conducting, I would like to estimate the Spearman rank correlation on some data that has known quantities of measurement error and range restriction. How could I go about correcting the observed Spearman rank correlation for these biases? Can I follow the same steps used to adjust Pearson correlations? Thank you in advance.

<sup>1</sup>Mendoza, J. L., & Mumford, M. (1987). Corrections for attenuation and range restriction on the predictor. Journal of Educational Statistics, 12(3), 282-293.
<sup>2</sup>Sackett, P. R., & Yang, H. (2000). Correction for range restriction: an expanded typology. Journal of Applied Psychology, 85(1), 112.
<sup>3</sup>Hunter, J. E., Schmidt, F. L., & Le, H. (2006). Implications of direct and indirect range restriction for meta-analysis methods and findings. Journal of Applied Psychology, 91(3), 594.

Comment: Spearman's correlation is Pearson correlation on the ranked data. Do you know the measurement error and range of the ranks? I'd have thought you only know that for the ranked data.

Comment: Hey Jeremy, thanks for your reply. Do you mind clarifying what you mean by "range of the ranks?" If you're referring to the range of the unrestricted data, then yes, I do know that.

Comment: Range restriction requires the variance of the data, and the variance that you would have had if the data weren't restricted (I think). It's weird to think of the variance of the ranks without restriction, without ties, the variance is just a function of the sample size.

Comment: Maybe some context would be useful. This is apart of a Monte Carlo study I'm conducting to examine factors which bias estimating the predictive validity of a psychometric test - two of the nonfocal factors are measurement error and range restriction. As it's a simulation, I have the both the restricted and unrestricted data. I wanted to compare the performance of the Spearman rank correlation to the fully-corrected Pearson correlation for predictor and criterion scale scores. Given that's my goal, it seems like I need to correct the Spearman rank correlation as well to make it comparable.